# C++ How can I code a generic struct to hold any enum

Tags: c++, enums, casting

I'm pretty new to C++ so apologies in advance,

Let's say I have 2 enum's:

```
enum Side
{
    Left,
    Right
};

enum Direct
{
    Forward,
    Backward
};
```

I want an object where I can save the enum value and then retrieve it agnostic of which actual enum was used,

e.g:

```
Direct direction = Direct::Left;
myStruct.genericEnum = direction;
Side side = myStruct.genericEnum;
```

How could this be done? should I be using generic types? (not sure I understand them well enough to use them), do I need to save the enum as an int in myStruct and then explicitly cast when reading the value back? (this seems messy to me) Thanks in advance

Comment: in your example, what would `side` equal after the assignment?  If it is Forward then it is not that hard to do, in fact it is a native feature of C++ to go between enum and integer types

Comment: You should probably decide whether they should be different enums or not. If there is an urgent reason for that, you should not try to "trick" the compiler, because different things _are_ different things. There is a good reason why the compiler is such a bitch about types, because when you try to do something that is not allowed, it is wrong 90% of the time, too. You'll likely shoot yourself in the foot as well, because (int)Left == (int) Forward. On the other hand, if there is no urgent reason, you should just make _one_ enum for all 4 directions.

Comment: What is point of this interchangeability of enums? Such an idea seems to be bug-prone!

Comment: Maybe it will help if you describe what exactly you are trying to model: for example a car (cardinal direction with turns), robot (turns, then moves in any direction), airhockey puck (moves freely in any direction), rook in chessgame (moves only along fixed axes), etc. Different models have different needs, and people will be more likely to find a good answer if they know what exactly you want.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a union:

```
struct MyStruct {
  union { Side side; Direct direct; } genericEnum;
};

Direct direction = Direct::Left;
myStruct.genericEnum.direct = direction;
Side side = myStruct.genericEnum.side;
```

but I have to ask: are you really sure that this is a sensible thing to be doing? It seems like asking for trouble.

(Generics as such aren't what you're looking for: they're purely a compile-time construct, and won't help with storing a value of one type and interpreting it as another.)

Comment: Not true -- generics are evaluated at runtime. But C++ doesn't have generics, so I'm unsure how the discussion works at that point. (Note that Generics are distinct from C++ Templates)

Comment: Problem with this is that now Left == Forward, and Right == Backward, and you have no way of knowing what is what.

Comment: Billy: I assumed Paul was referring to templates, which are how you implement such genericity as C++ has. dm.skt: yes, it's horrible, which is why I said "it seems like asking for trouble".

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Generics in Java are pure compile-time construct (only one class exists at runtime). They are both compile-time and runtime in C#.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: C++ class templates are strict superset of generics and as such are generics.

Comment: @Jan: "Only one class exists at runtime" <-- Exactly -- the stuff to differentiate which types are being acted upon happends at *runtime*. Templates do this at compile time. It's not a strict superset; while the constructs can be used to accomplish similar things they're based on very different conceptual ideas. Templates are "facny-pants find and replace", generics are not. If you try to think of one in terms of the other you're going to be confused when e.g. overloading doesn't behave like you'd think it would.

Comment: @Jan: This article is specifically about C# but Java works the same way. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx Examine the generated intermediate language or bytecode if you don't believe me :)

Answer (score 1):

This couldn't be done with "Generic types" because C++ does not have such types.

All enumerations are effectively integers. The "Generic Enum" you're looking for is an integer.

Comment: Well, class templates are "generic types". They behave differently than in java and are much more powerful.

Comment: @Jan: Not really true. "Generic type" implies that the genericity is determined at runtime rather than at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing direction and side in some strange way. Should structure hold both of them? Look at `union` it can hold one of the types, but not mix it.